# Does Handlebars evaluate null to true?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I require another controller in the application controller:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['login'],
  ...
```

Then I try to use some of the properties of the login controller in the application template:

```
            {{#if controllers.login.token}}
                <li>
                    <a {{action logout}} href="#/">log out</a>
                </li>
            {{else}}
                <li>
                    <a href="#/login">log in</a>
                </li>
            {{/if}}
```

When I write `{{log controllers.login.token}}` directly over the `#if` I get `null`.

But the if branch is still shown, not the else branch.

Comment: If your `'null'` is a string then it will be casted to `true`.

Comment: I think I located the problem. I wrote a `null` into `localStorage` but when I looked into the storage, there was the string `'null'` inside of it. So when I regained the value on a page-reload, `localStorage` delivered this string...

Answer (score 1):

null is falsey.  Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jivoqa/1/edit

`{{log xyz}}` is deceptive, it logs it when the page is being built, not necessarily what the value still is.  You'd be better off doing `{{xyz}}` and just tossing it in the page to see what it is.

Comment: still get `null` and the if still evaluates as if it was `true`

Comment: Are you actually seeing null?  if so then that's a string, and strings that aren't empty are true, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jivoqa/2/edit

Comment: yes it was a string. `localStorage` converted the `null` silently, didn't even think the problem would be back there. thank you anyway :)